# como reemplazar caracter de un string por otro?

Tags: javascript, array, string, function

hola alguien sabe como resolverlo? lo intente con mil formulas y nada

```
> function fakeBinary2(string) {
```

La funcion llamada 'fakeBinary' recibe como argumento un string con numeros y debe devolver un string en donde se remplaza los
numeros menores de 5 con '0'y los numeros iguales o mayores a 5 con '1'

```
  // Por ej:

  // fakeBinary2('5627') devuelve "1101"

  // fakeBinary("729") devuelve "101"

  // Tu código aca:
```

}
no se como encarar el enunciado creo, intente haciendo un array de "string" pero cada elemento queda como un string entonces no se como indicar "si es menor a 5 remplazar por 1" y etc. espero que se entienda

```
     function fakeBinary2(string) {
  string = string.split(",");
  for (let i=0; i< string,length; i++ ){
    if (string[i] == "2"||"3"||"4"){
      string.replace(i, "0")
    } else if (string[i] == "5"||"6"||"7"||"8"||"9"){
      string.replace(i, "1")}
  } return string;
}
```

Comment: y donde están tus intentos?... cual es error que tienes?...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev ahi agregue uno de los intentos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero se encuentre bien, observo que esta quizás iniciando con la programación, recuerde siempre debe primero hacer un diagrama de flujo y/o diseño de la solución a implementar ante su problemática.

Le comparto un código de ejemplo de cómo solucionar su problema/enunciado, lo proporciono como guía y base para que usted resuelva dudas, esta no es la única ni la mejor solución; pero eso es lo grandioso de programar, existen muchas soluciones ante una problemática.

¡Saludos, y espero continue estudiando este gran arte que es la programación!

```
/**
 * @author: NoeVG
 * @about: Function que de vuelve un cadena en binario falso,
 * recibe como argumento un string con numeros y 
 * debe devolver un string en donde se remplaza los 
 * numeros menores de 5 con '0'y los numeros 
 * iguales o mayores a 5 con '1'
 * @args: string
 * @return: string
 * */
function fakeBinary(data){
    // Definimos un nuevo array para poder
    // recorrer caracter por caracter el string dado
    let newArrayData = []
    
    // Definimos un nuevo string que contendra el binario falso
    let stringFakeBinary = data;

    // Convertimos el string a un array
    // Esta es una forma , pero puedes implementar muchas otras
    let arrayData = data.split("")
    
    // Iteramos cada caracter del string transformado en array
    arrayData.forEach( caracter => {
        // Validamos si el caracter es un numero,
        // isNaN() regresa valor falso si es un numero,
        // o regresa valor true si no es un numero
        if( isNaN(caracter) === false ){
            // El caracter es un numero
            // Validamos la condición para el binario falso
            if( parseInt(caracter) < 5 ){
                // Guardamos en esta pocisión el valor de '0'
                newArrayData.push('0')
            }else if( parseInt(caracter) >= 5){
                // Guardamos en esta pocisión el valor de '1'
                newArrayData.push('1')
            }else{
                // Si no se cumple ninguna condición
                // guardamos el caracter original
                newArrayData.push(caracter)
            }
        }else{
            // El caracter no es un numero, se trata de 
            // otro caracter, guardamos el caracter original
            newArrayData.push( caracter )
        }
    });
    // Convertimos el nuevo array "binario falso" a string
    stringFakeBinary = newArrayData.toString();
    return stringFakeBinary;
}
// --------- ejecución --------------
// Llamada a función con string
let data = "6eD51";
let binario_falso = fakeBinary(data);
// Mostramos en consola de depuración el valor
console.log("String original: ", data)
console.log("  Binario falso: ", binario_falso)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Respuesta rápida:

```
    function fakeBinary(str) {
        let myBinaryResult = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str[i] < 5) {
                myBinaryResult += "0";
            } else {
                myBinaryResult += "1";
            }
        }
        return myBinaryResult;
    }
```

### Explicación

Hola, te recomiendo refactorizar tu código, tomando en cuenta esto:

- Con un bucle for puedes recorrer caracter por caracter un string, por lo que no es necesario en este caso el paso de separarlo usando "split".
- Usa mayor que, menor que (<) y los que vayas a necesitar para escribir tus condicionales.
- Cuando quieras usar (||) en los condicionales, en tu caso, se debe colocar así

```
    str[i] == "2"||str[i] == "3"||str[i] == "4"
```

y no así

```
    str[i] == "2"||"3"||"4"
```

**Importante**

- Fíjate que creo un string vacío llamado "myBinaryResult" y lo voy agregando 1 o 0 respectivamente.
- El condicional dice que se agrega "0" si es menor a 5, y se agrega "1" en el caso contrario.

Un tema importante a aclarar, estoy comparando un string con un número

```
str[i] < 5
```

es como decir

```
"7" < 5
```

Esto no da error porque JavaScript por dentro convierte el string "7" a un número 7 ya que existe una comparación de "mayor que".

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo más simple de la siguiente manera:

```js
function fakeBinary2(string) {
    charArray = [...string]
    binaryArray = charArray.map(a => a > "5" ? "1" : "0")
    return binaryArray.join("")
}

console.log(fakeBinary2("0926"))
```

Con el operador [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) pasas cada carácter de string individualmente. Entonces si `string = "0925"`, `[...string]` es equivalente a `[ "0", "9", "2", "5" ]`.

Con [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) generas un nuevo arreglo en el que si los caracteres son mayores a `"5"` se reemplazan por `"1"` sino `"0"`.

Por último se concatenan todos los elementos del array en una cadena con [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).